# How to download return from google colab?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, google-colaboratory

I am using Google colab to analyze some data. I want to download the model file.
I have a code like that:

```java
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=1, batch_size=1,
```

I tried using the download(), but it doesn't work. Is there any way to download it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assuming that you are using Keras, because `model.save()` method return None so if you put it as `download()` method parameter, it will make an error. Just save model first then download it after that:

```
model.save('model_name.h5')
download('model_name.h5')
```

And make sure that you are at the correct directory that contain `model_name.h5` file. You can check that with `!ls` command.

Comment: I have tried it on collab and it works fine. Have you fixed it yet?

Comment: It crashes with error "name 'download' is not defined "

Comment: You need to import download method first before use it `from google.colab.files import download`